# Stylus 'for' cycle: possible to combine range and single values?

Tags: cycle, stylus

Is it possible to use both range and single values (combined) for the `for` cycle in Stylus ?

```
for item in range(2, 7) 14 33
    li:nth-child({item})
        color red
```

or

```
for item in 2..7 14 33
    li:nth-child({item})
        color red
```

that code is not working. It can only work if either range or a set of single values is used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, Stylus doesn't have anything like `concat` in the standard library, only `push`, but you can easily write it:

```
concat()
  ret = ()
  for item in arguments
    push(ret, item)
  ret

body
  for i in concat(range(0, 5), 10, 55)
    test: i
```

Answer (score 1):

```
concat()
  result = ()
  for arg in arguments
    for i in arg
      push(result, i)
  result

p(concat(tmp none 666 777 0..5)) // tmp (none) (666) (777) (0) (1) (2) (3) (4) (5)
```